# Convert a webmethod from c# to vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I did the web method below using C#. I'm tryin to convert this into VB.NET, but I'm missing something. I'm using it with an ajax calling, from a paginator/sorter table plugin.

```
[WebMethod( EnableSession = true )]
public static object listaPessoas(int jtStartIndex = 0, 
                                  int jtPageSize = 0, 
                                  string jtSorting = null)
{
    return new { Result = "OK", 
                 Records = persons.ToList(), 
                 TotalRecordCount = persons.count };
}
```

First, error in VB - I can't leave the parameters as optional("*Attribute WebMethod cannot be applied to a method with optional parameters*"):

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function listaPessoas(Optional ByVal jtStartIndex As Integer = 0, 
                             Optional ByVal jtPageSize As Integer = 0, 
                             Optional ByVal jtSorting As String = Nothing)
```

Second, I don't know how to return the message "OK" and the list of people.

Can anyone me help to convert this into VB.NET?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `optional` and declare the webmethod attribute `<WebMethod(EnableSession := True)>`? If you need optional parameters you should overload the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can't use optional parameters with WebMethods. You can use overloading. Example:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function listaPessoas(jtStartIndex As Integer, jtPageSize As Integer)

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function listaPessoas(jtStartIndex As Integer, jtPageSize As Integer, jtSorting As String)
```

The C# object returned is an anonymous object. The VB syntax is:

```
Return New With { .Result = "OK", 
                  .Records = persons.ToList(), 
                  .TotalRecordCount = persons.count }
```